# R proFIA "No MS1 data found in file" error using MSConvert-ed files

Tags: r, file-type

I have mass spectrometry data that is initially generated as Thermo RAW files, but I then use MSConvert to convert the files to .mzXML format so that I can analyse my data using the [proFIA package functions](https://rdrr.io/bioc/proFIA/man/). When I try to load my metabolomics data as .mzXML files using proFIA in RStudio, I keep getting the error message:

```
Error in readRawData(fileName(object), includeMSn = includeMSn) : 
  No MS1 data found in file MassSpecData.mzXML!
```

When I use the following code:

```
require(proFIA)

df <- proFIAset(
  path = "MassSpecDataFolder",
  ppm = 2, #From example in function documentation
  parallel = FALSE, 
  noiseEstimation = TRUE #Recommended in documentation
)
```

From looking around, I see that this issue occurs with XCMS and the [responses recommend](http://www.metabolomics-forum.com/index.php?topic=1341.0) ensuring that "SIM as spectra" and "SRM as spectra" options are selected as well as the MS1 peak selected using the Peak Picking tool. However, these tips do not fix this issue and I cannot find any guidance on this issue for people using the proFIA package.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!